# Incorporate JQuery into Typescript VS 2013

Tags: jquery, typescript

I'm new to Typescript.  I'm using VS 2013 and have the typescript templates installed but moving over existing javascript code fails when trying to compile the $ directive in JQuery. Everything I've seen says to get a .d.ts file from definitelytyped.org, but there are literally 1000's of files and, again literally no instructions.

I've use NuGet to add this file to my project, but yet the error persists.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
   <package id="jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped" version="3.0.6" targetFramework="net45" />
 </packages>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings), Oficial TypeScript Definition Manager. It will help you download the necessary files.

To use, first you must install [NodeJs](https://nodejs.org/en/) then install it by typing `npm install typings --global` using prompt command. After that, go to the root of your project using the prompt command and then type `typings install jquery --save`.

Comment: I can't imagine that I have to use yet another framework to use a framework.  I don't want Node.js but I do want jQuery with typescript.

Comment: Well, it is not a framework. NodeJS is an awesome tool that can be used to make your life easier as a developer. Don't judge it before knowing it, give a try :)

Comment: from the Node.js web site "Node.js is a very powerful JavaScript-based framework/platform built on Google Chrome's JavaScript V8 Engine.  "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though VS 13 has a problem with NuGet packages but fixed in 14.  Thanks to @nycdotnet and @vladima
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1759